# Using nohup on remote SSH script, inside the script itself

Tags: linux, ssh, nohup

I'm trying to use nohup + redirection + background operator ("&") to run a remote script via SSH and disconnect.

This works:

```
ssh -n fred@fredbox.local 'nohup sudo /opt/scripts/do-thing.sh arg1 arg2 >/dev/null 2>&1 '
```

I want to encapsulate the nohup parts inside a wrapper that runs the actual remote script, but does the nohup and output redirection. But it just doesn't work.

Example remote script "/opt/scripts/remote-exec-script.sh":

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -o xtrace
set -o errexit
set -o nounset

ARG1=${1}
ARG2="${2}

nohup sudo /opt/scripts/do-thing.sh $ARG1 $ARG2  >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Putting the nohup and output redirection in the remote script itself does not work.

I do have xtrace on, so I even tried capturing stderr in the SSH line like so

```
ssh -n fred@fredbox.local "/opt/scripts/remote-exec-script.sh >/dev/null 2>&1"
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the problem; it has to do with `pty` allocation (`-tt` flags on ssh) and sudo.

TL;DR: This works as I wanted it to, as long as the remote script satisfies the following conditions:

- Does not need sudo
- If they need sudo, the remote user has NO_PASSWORD sudo for the operations in question
- Alternatively, one can do it **without** `pty` allocation is one uses the `-S` flag for sudo, to accept the password via stdin. I did not use this method.
- All output is captured by the remote script

I used option (2) -- remote user has passwordless sudo.